# How to get raw EMG signal without offset

Tags: arduino, amplifier, biopotential, dc-offset

I am trying to build an EMG sensor plus Arduino from DIY found on internet.

Everythings works fine, but I want only the raw signal for some bigger project.

The circuit is below:

[image]

The  signal looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, when it reaches the value 0, it stops. I tried to get the real raw signal and modified the code, but nothing changed, so I think it's the hardware. Any guess in how to remove this offset? Should the configuration of the TL072 be different?

Comment: Post schematics instead of that drawing of your breadboard.  Fritzing van make them, and they are much more useful than the sketch.

Comment: The Arduino ADC does not accept voltages below ground.  You will have to add a DC offset to your AC signal to move it to a range (0VDC to 5VDC) that the Arduino can digitize.

Comment: That is to say, you need to add an offset, not get rid of one.

Comment: thank's for answer. to add offset do i need another amplifier or how it's the best way to do this?

Comment: @fgtuw29, use an op amp output to put the offset at vref of the inamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUOXZD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That adds 2.5V to the AC signal.  It also inverts the AC, but I don't think that will bother things.

Depending on how you have your existing TL072 connected, you could probably do this all in that one stage.

But, you didn't post your schematic and I don't feel like drawing one from your breadboard sketch, so I'll just leave this as is.

---

You've got 5V on the Arduino, but it is usually very noisy.  I've used 5V in the schematic just to make it clear that you need a regulated voltage.  The two 9V batteries aren't regulated, so you can't generate your 2.5V from them.

You might be able to use the Arduino 5V if you use a large enough value for C1 to clean up all the noise.  I've put a 1µF in.  That ought to do as a starting place.

Comment: i try to make your circuit, but i get only 1023 value so, something went wrong. maybe i connect something wrong. i can't find all elements in Fritzing, i try to do it tomorow.